# prefix println statements in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'd like to achieve the following goals using groovy:

1. Prepend (prefix) all `println` statements in groovy with the current time
2. I want the continue printing those `println` statements to print on standard out (console in my case).
3. I want to do it at one generic place, so that I don't have to individually modify all of these `println` statements.

Is there anything (like groovy aspect, log4j console appender etc.) that I could use to have all `println` statements prepend the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metaprogramming.  You could have PrintStream.metaClass.invokeMethod intercept the call to the println method and add the date to the passed in string.

Something like this, adapted from example code in Subramaniam's "Programming Groovy":

```
System.out.metaClass.invokeMethod = {String name, args ->
    def validMethod = System.out.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    if (! validMethod)
    {
        return System.out.metaClass.invokeMissingMethod(delegate,name,args)
    }

    if ( validMethod.name == 'println')
    {
       args[0] = "${(new Date()).toString()} : ${args[0]}".toString()
    }
    validMethod.invoke(delegate,args)
}
```